# WriteProcessMemory with multiple Offsets C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I have struggled with a very annoying problem lately with writing to Process memory in c++... I can not write to process memory with multiple offsets! Even though there are thousands of pages explaining how you fix this problem, it still seems to not work for me. I have been searching around on google all day long, and found many examples of how to fix this problem, but it still seems to not work for me.

So, let me first explain how I am writing to process memory myself, and you could possibly correct it afterwards.

Let us say I have a base address of: 0x04AF3C94

First offsets as: 0x1C

Second offsets as: 0x20

Third as: 0x568

And fourth as: 0x134

How I am doing this myself:

```
DWORD offset1 = 0x1C;
DWORD offset2 = 0x20;
DWORD offset3 = 0x568;
DWORD offset4 = 0x134;

DWORD base = 0x04AF3C94;
DWORD pointer;
DWORD pointer2;
DWORD pointer3;
DWORD pointer4;
DWORD pointer5;
ReadProcessMemory(handle, LPVOID(base), &pointer, sizeof(pointer), 0);
ReadProcessMemory(handle, LPVOID(pointer + offset1), &pointer2, sizeof(pointer2), 0);
ReadProcessMemory(handle, LPVOID(pointer2 + offset2), &pointer3, sizeof(pointer3), 0);
ReadProcessMemory(handle, LPVOID(pointer3 + offset3), &pointer4, sizeof(pointer4), 0);
ReadProcessMemory(handle, LPVOID(pointer4 + offset4), &pointer5, sizeof(pointer4), 0);

int value = 500;
WriteProcessMemory(handle, LPVOID(pointer5), &value, sizeof(value), 0);
```

As you can see, if I have 4 offsets such as in this example, I am adding every  offset one at a time to the base address, until I got one value that stores every offset added to the baseaddress.
This apparently don't work, what should I do!?

Comment: _This apparently don't work_ -- what *exactly* doesn't work, you experience a crash at reading, writing or the universe suddenly reboots itself?

Comment: Well, if I have for example I value I want to change, it won't change... The program does not crash or anything, however the values I'm trying to change are simply not being affected at all.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reply to all with your description, but in the MSDN they say that ReadProcessMemory read memory from where it is asked to the given buffer. It means when you call...

```
ReadProcessMemory(handle, LPVOID(base), &pointer, sizeof(pointer), 0);
```

...your "pointer" will be filled with what is at the "base" address. So it will contain an address that is numericaly the value of the four bytes at address "base". This is probably not what you want, because if you didn't stored something there before, it's indeterminate. And if so, it will probably crash when you use "pointer".

If you want to read the memory at adresse "base + offset1" with that function, what you have to do is:

```
ReadProcessMemory(handle, LPVOID(base + offset1), some_buffer, some_buffer_size, 0);
```

Where some_buffer is a valid buffer you have to declare somewhere.